# Getting started with scripts in Bedrock edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've recently learned about creating behavior packs and functions, and while on that journey I learned that I can write scripts in `JavaScript`, even in Bedrock edition. However, I'm having trouble finding resources for getting started. Like any system I need to know how things work before I can start writing code. The most I've found so far is that there are two different types of scripts I can create:

- Client
- Server

However, I have no idea how to get started. Most systems have some sort of `main` function to start with, but I can't seem to find anything in the plethora of information available on the web on how to get started. I just need the equivalent of a *hello world*, and some reliable source of documentation.

---

How can I get started with a *hello world* script for Minecraft Bedrock edition?

- Bonus, is there a reliable source of documentation for things like events and objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [the Minecraft site](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/addons) and scroll to the bottom and download the vanilla behaviour pack. Inside you will find documentation.

Note that JavaScript operates on a start at line 1 then work down (for the most part, while this isn't exactly true due to some stuff like functions being boosted but that's what matters) rather then having a main function. It doesn't need to execute inside of a function either, it just executes the first statement, then the next, the next, etc..